# True Displacement on animated metaballs?

Tags: modeling, materials, modifiers

The subdivision modifier isn't available for metaballs, so I don't know how to do true displacement on them. Also, when I try to turn the metaballs into a mesh, the animation doesn't work anymore.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "true displacement"? Do you mean not faked with a shader (ie a Normal or Bump map), or do you mean displaced with a UV dependent Displacement texture?

Comment: Hello, the subdiv modifier isn't available but iirc there is an option for the metaobject resolution somewhere

Comment: I mean like being able to use the displace node output for a material and getting a partially reshaped mesh when you render it out.

Comment: Oh alright, you are talking about the displacement modifier, not the subdivision modifier. You can't use it but you can use True Displacement with Cycles though